# modify stack item count & display listview/gridview inside stackview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, count, stackview

I have 2 questions to ask here. 
I am refering http://www.broculos.net/en/article/android-101-how-create-stackview-widget to create a stackview widget.

1. The default stackview displays 4 items stacked behind each other. Can we change this count ?
   For example, in attached image http://www.broculos.net/sites/default/files/resize/content/honeybuzz_widget_preview-200x125.png , HoneyBuzz widget shows 4 items, but the Map widget shows 3. 
   How to achieve this ?
2. Also i wish to know can we add Listview & Gridview inside stackview. Means, as we can can display text/images in a single stack item, can we display a  list/grid & scroll through it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No you cant.
2. I think scrolling in a stack list view would prevent users from changing "card" in stack, so that would not be possible

From android developers website:

> Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with XML
>   Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based
>   on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view
>   widget.
>
> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> - FrameLayout LinearLayout RelativeLayout And the following widget    classes:
> - AnalogClock
> - Button
> - Chronometer
> - ImageButton
> - ImageView
> - TextView
> - ViewFlipper
> - ListView
> - GridView
> - StackView
> - AdapterViewFlipper
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Comment: By any way, like writing our custom Stackview or something .. ?